# Check if an object is a QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an object variable `obj`. Is it possible to check whether its a Queryset or not?

(Couldn't find any posts on this on searching)

Comment: `from django.db.models.query import QuerySet; isinstance(obj, QuerySet)`

Comment: `from django.db.models.query import QuerySet; isinstance(obj, QuerySet)` leads to `Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks` with `django-stubs==1.9.0` in mypy

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use python built-in function [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
isinstance(your_qs, QuerySet)
```

Comment: `from django.db.models.query import QuerySet; isinstance(obj, QuerySet)` leads to `Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks` with `django-stubs==1.9.0` in mypy

Answer (score 4):

You can get the type of obj by python's inbuilt type()

Try this :

```
  type(obj)
```

It will return as below if its a Queryset

```
  <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

Comment: This was useful for inspecting what was needed to be done, @DimaKudosh then applied the outcome to declare is instance(). Thank you.